# Combinations of two groups of people

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose that $15$ people are divided in a random manner into two groups of 10 and 5. What is probability that two particular people A and B would be in the same group?

My attempt:

$$P(A \cap B)= \binom{15}{10} \binom{15}{5} $$

Am I doing the right thing?

Comment: That number is far greater than $1$, so can't be a probability.  I'd go case by case:  what's the probability that they are both in the big group?  What's the probability that they are both in the small group?

Comment: @lulu, the probability that they are both in a big group  is $\binom{15}{10}$ and for the small group $\binom{15}{5}$.

Comment: @Lady Those are the number of ways of selecting a group of ten and a group of five.  Your sample space is $\binom{15}{10} = \binom{15}{5}$ since choosing one group determines the other.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, then $\frac{\binom{15}{2}} {\binom{15}{10}}$

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are among the group of ten, then you must also select $8$ of the other $13$ members of the group to be in the group of ten, so the number of ways $A$ and $B$ could both be in the group of ten is $\binom{2}{2}\binom{13}{8}$.  How many ways could they both be in the group of $5$?  What probability does that give you?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, hence $\frac{\binom{2}{22} \binom{13}{8}}{\binom{15}{10}}*\frac{\binom{2}{2} \binom{13}{3}}{\binom{15}{5}}$

Comment: Almost.  The two events are mutually exclusive, so you should be adding.  Also, you should edit your question to show your attempt rather than placing it in the comments, where it might be missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of ways of selecting a group of ten people and a group of five people from a group of $15$ people is 
$$\binom{15}{10}\binom{5}{5} = \binom{15}{10}$$
since once we choose ten people to be in one group, the other five must be in the other group.

If $A$ and $B$ are both in the group of ten, then eight of the other thirteen people must also be in that group.  Thus, the number of ways that $A$ and $B$ could both be selected for the group of ten is 
$$\binom{2}{2}\binom{13}{8}$$

If $A$ and $B$ are both in the group of five, then three of the other thirteen people must also be in that group.  Thus, the number of ways that $A$ and $B$ could both be selected for the group of five is 
$$\binom{2}{2}\binom{13}{3}$$

Since these events are mutually exclusive, the number of favorable cases is 
$$\binom{2}{2}\binom{13}{8} + \binom{2}{2}\binom{13}{3}$$

Hence, the probability that $A$ and $B$ are in the same group is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{13}{8} + \dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{13}{3}}{\dbinom{15}{10}}$$

**Note:**  In the comments, you arrived at the answer 
$$\frac{\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{13}{8}}{\dbinom{15}{10}} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{13}{3}}{\dbinom{15}{5}}$$

You multiplied when you should have added.

The [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) states that if there are $m$ ways of performing one task and $n$ ways of performing another task that can be performed independently of the first task, then there are $mn$ ways of performing both tasks.  We used the Multiplication Principle here when we calculated the number of ways of selecting both $A$ and $B$ to be in the group of five.  We chose both $A$ and $B$ *and* three of the other thirteen people in 
$$\binom{2}{2}\binom{13}{3}$$
ways.  However, it does not apply to the number of ways that both $A$ and $B$ could be selected to be in the group of $10$ *or* the group of $5$ since these events cannot happen simultaneously.

The word *and* is an indication that you should multiply; the word *or* is an indication that you should add.

The [Addition Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum) states that if one event can occur in $m$ ways and another event that cannot occur at the same time can occur in $n$ ways, then the number of ways that one of the events could occur is $m + n$.  Since it is not possible for $A$ and $B$ to simultaneously be in the group of $10$ and the group of $5$, you should have added the probability that $A$ and $B$ are both in the group of $10$ and the probability that they are both in the group of $5$.  Had you done so, you would have obtained 
$$\frac{\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{13}{8}}{\dbinom{15}{10}} + \frac{\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{13}{3}}{\dbinom{15}{5}}$$
This is equivalent to my answer since 
$$\binom{15}{10} = \frac{15!}{10!5!} = \frac{15!}{5!10!} = \binom{15}{5}$$

In general, 
$$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n - k}$$
since 
$$\binom{n}{n - k} = \frac{n!}{(n - k)![n - (n - k)]!} = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!k!} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!} = \binom{n}{k}$$

Comment: Since the special people are mentioned we have $\dbinom{1}{1}\dbinom{1}{1}$, not $\dbinom{2}{2}$. The species is $X.X.E_3(X). E_{10}(X) + E_5(X).X.X.E_8(X)$

Answer (score 1):

We can calculate this probability without using combinations as follows:

Call the group of 10 people $G_{10}$ and the group of five people $G_5$. The probability that $A$ and $B$ are in the same group is:

$P(A \in G_{10} \land B \in G_{10}) +  P(A \in G_5 \land B \in G_15)$

$=P(A \in G_{10})P(B \in G_{10} | A \in G_{10}) +  P(A \in G_5)P(B \in G_5|A \in G_5)$

$=\frac{10}{15}\frac{9}{14} + \frac{5}{15}\frac{4}{14}=\frac{90+20}{210}=\frac{11}{21}$